# Getting DTED Data (Elevation) Between Two Points using.NET

Tags: .net, elevation, dted

I want to get DTED data (elevation) between two points (on a line).

Is there any built-in function for this purpose or I should implement it on my own?

What I want is similar to Linear Line of Sight (LLOS), but it should be on a direct line. I want to check if there is collision between two points or not.

Comment: What software package does this pertain to?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Your own interpolation, or did you find a package?